# ESQL/C functions which can be called from C code directly?

Tags: linux, unix, migration, informix

Can anybody tell me some ESQL/C functions which can be called directly from C code? I am using Informix as the database and HP-UX as the O.S..

Comment: 5-10 functions name would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of ESQL/C is that you write your code containing embedded SQL statements and then run the ESQL/C code through the ESQL/C preprocessor to generate C code that the C compiler will then compile to object code for use.

The [ESQL/C Programmer's Manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_11.70.0/com.ibm.esqlc.doc/esqlc.htm) describes how use ESQL/C.  You can find more information at the [IBM Informix 11.70 Information Centre](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_11.70.0/com.ibm.welcome.doc/welcome.htm), including links to download the PDF file(s).

The ESQL/C Programmer's Manual documents the functions that you're expected to call direct from the C portion of the ESQL/C program.  The interfaces that speak directly to the server are not documented as C functions but as embedded SQL statements.  You use those undocumented interface functions at your own risk — I recommend not taking that risk (but I am biassed since I work on Informix for IBM).